# Deleting a node in a circular linked list c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

EDITED:
using c++ to code.

```
void circularList::deleteNode(int x)
{
    node *current;
    node *temp;
    current = this->start;

    while(current->next != this->start)
    {
        if(current->next->value == x)
        {
            temp = current->next;
            current->next = current->next->next;
            delete current->next;
        }
    else{ 
            current = current->next;
             }
    }
}
```

Added the else i'm sorry i kinda forgot to copy that part of the code and yes it is for learning purposes. I'm new to coding with c++ and probably come off as a noob sorry about that.

Also as for  this line of code

this->start->value == x

im not sure what you mean by it or where you think it goes, yes there are nodes in the linked list and assume that it will always have at lease 1 node all the time.

Comment: Gets stuck in the loop, deletes the wrong node, leaks memory, can't delete 1st node.

Comment: ... and probably never deletes the last node.

Comment: About your update asking about `this->start->value == x` - I didn't mean that you need that line of code in the function, but that you need to consider how to properly handle what to do when deleting the node that `this->start` points to.

Comment: Of course, matt pointed out that as the code stands, you won't be able to delete that node (even if it's the one that holds a match for `x`), since the search starts at the node after the start and ends when you get back to the start. Of course that might be because, as matt also suggests, you're treating the start node as a sentinel that doesn't really belong to the list (but then you don't really have a circular linked list).

Answer (score 6):

Think about this two lines:

`current->next = current->next->next;`

`delete current->next;`

Try to determine what you are actually deleting (no its not `current->next;`, at least not the one you want to delete).

Comment: Yep, this is another problem.

Answer (score 6):

You never move to the next node in your while loop. After your if, you should have:

```
else
    current = current->next;
```

Also, you might want to consider returning from the function after you've found the node (unless you suspect that two nodes have the same value).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Justin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430910/deleting-a-node-in-a-circular-linked-list-c/2430921#2430921) and [Let_Me-Be's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430910/deleting-a-node-in-a-circular-linked-list-c/2430919#2430919) answers, consider what you might need to take care of when

```
this->start->value == x
```

If you don't handle that right, you'll lose your whole list (or crash trying to get to it)...

Comment: currently it looks like it would never check the start node

Comment: @matt: right, I missed that.  But once that bug was fixed, this one would be next on the list, no?

Comment: yeah, and is by far  A LOT worse.

Comment: the way I like to fix this problem is to not make start a pointer to a node in the list, but a dummy node itself in the list. that way you don't have to worry about checking this edge case, well, at least that's what I do for doubly linked lists, and in this case you would have to make sure the dummy node's value was set to something that would NEVER be passed to this function.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have only a singularly linked list?

Have you considered the STL, perhaps a `deque`?

Or, if you must have a single linked list then why not take something that it 90% STL (;-) and look at the Boost libraries?

You do seem to be reinventing the wheel here. Why not take some existing - and tested - code and use that?

Comment: See all those comments? You wouldn't get them if you used an existing, tried and tested solution.   IS there something unique about your singly linked list that makes it different from all the previously coded and tested singly linked lists? You probably have more important things to spend your time on (just trying to be helpful - honest)

Comment: I'm guessing this is for school/education.

Comment: mawg - good points, but I assumed this was a learning exercise.

Comment: though you probably should be able to tell the problems with this code too. ESPECIALLY if you're coding in c++

Comment: If it's a learning exercise, then perhaps learning the debugger might useful.  I would suggest that OP step through his code, examining it as he goes and really understand what it actually does.

If the code has no GUI, I strongly recommend using Eclipse as an IDE, especially because of the myriad of plugings available.

If OP is not using Linux, then one look at this picture might convince him to do so ... http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/all.png  tehre's nothing better for linked lists (sigh! If only there were a version for windows, or I could get X-windows working with Cygwin)

Comment: OP, you might also want to get used to the idea of writing unit tests for your code. I strongly recommend CPPunit, but use whatever you prefer (CPPunit also has a good Eclipse plugin).

Every time you change your code, just run the tests to see if you broke anything.

And, since you are learning and want to do things the right way, you ought to have written a design document (and had it reviewed) before you started testing.

Answer (score 0):

Is "deleting a node from linked list" the issue or "deleting a node from a ***circular*** linked list" the issue?

The difference from non-circular to circular is the line:

```
while(current->next != this->start)
```

If the list were non circular it would have been

```
while(current->next != NULL )
```

Apart from that, there are issues with the code snippet, which others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing: Do you check that you have at least one valid node in your list before you call deleteNode?

I ask this as your function does not check for a NULL-value of the start element.

The solution would be to add the line

if(start == NULL) return

as first line of your method to avoid this.